# Jira SOAP API get all users with Python

Tags: python, api, soap, jira

I am trying to get all users in relation to the existing groups in JIRA without getting the group names directly out of the DB. Since there is no "getAllUsers" I don't know if it is possible. I was thinking of "getProjectWithSchemesById" and filter the returned Groups (if this is a way to get ALL groups). Hope you have some ideas

...using Jira 4.3.4 and Python 2.7.1+

Comment: Try getGroup("jira-users") and the RemoteGroup that comes back has an array of RemoteUsers in it.

Comment: Tried that and realised that not all of the users in my Jira are in that group. So I needed a different way to find out all users in relation to the groups.

Problem got solved anyway, because Groups are given now through a read file. Thanks for your answer tho =)